# Artifactory : automation with packer and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifactory, terraform

I am looking for a way to automate Artifactory deployment on AWS with packer.
I want a simple configuration : 
AWS ALB + [ASG:just 1 EC2] Artifactory + EFS for Blob + AWS RDS PostgreSQL

1. I wrote Terraform and infrastructure is setup working properly
2. I build Artifactory AMI with packer easily (I build from RPM
   installation
3. In AWS userdata :

I update blob path /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data to point AWS EFS

I would like to change db from derby to Postgre, following this url : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PostgreSQL

I adjust $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties and download the JDBC driver corresponding to your PostgreSQL.

Everything is OK, Artifactory detect new empty database, create object ... but Artifactory do not start. I have and error with master.key : here is my catalina.out :

> Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"] Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"] Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"] Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service [Catalina] Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23 Jul 26, 2018 2:00:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] Jul
>   26, 2018 2:00:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDescriptor INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor
>   [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml]
>   2018-07-26 14:00:18 [UNDEFINED] [INFO ] Fetched Artifactory
>   [artifactory.home=null] from servlet context 2018-07-26 14:00:19
>   [UNDEFINED] [INFO ] Resolved Artifactory home by logger
>   [artifactory.home=/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory]. 14:00:19.438
>   [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG
>   org.artifactory.converter.VersionProviderImpl - Last Artifactory
>   database version is: v610 14:00:19.460 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO
>   org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl - Triggering PRE_INIT
>   conversion, from v610 to v610 14:00:19.460 [localhost-startStop-2]
>   INFO org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl - Finished
>   PRE_INIT conversion, current version is: v610 2018-07-26 14:00:19
>   [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO ] master.key file currently missing - waiting for
>   Access to create it. Reattempting to check master.key file existence
>   in 1 second. 2018-07-26 14:00:20 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO ] master.key file
>   currently missing - waiting for Access to create it. Reattempting to
>   check master.key file existence in 1 second.

Any idea is welcome :-)

Comment: Is the master.key eventually created? it should be in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/security/master.key

Comment: Do you have any further information in the artifactory.log file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Terraform template to install jFrog Artifactory. I think you can use something similar to https://github.com/jfrog/JFrog-Cloud-Installers/blob/master/Terraform/userdata.sh for setting Artifactory configuration files.